# Is the converse of the Reduction Theorem for Torsion Points true?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve defined over a number field $K$.

It's a well known result that, for a prime $v$ of $K$ such that the reduction of the elliptic curve $\tilde{E}/k$ is non-singular (here $k$ denotes the corresponding residue field of the completion $K_v$), the reduction map $E(K)[m] \to \tilde{E}(k)$ is injective (for $m$ coprime to $p=char(k)$).

This allows one to quickly find a method for finding the torsion subgroup of an elliptic curve. For instance, for the elliptic curve $E$ defined by $y^2=x^3+3$ with discriminant $\Delta=-3^5 2^4$, we can check that $\#\tilde{E}({\mathbb{F}_5})=6$ and $\#\tilde{E}({\mathbb{F}_7})=13$, so obviously the torsion of $E$ is trivial. My question concerns the reciprocal of this result, namely:

**1) Is it true that $\#E(K)_{\text{torsion}} = \gcd\{ \#\tilde{E}({k}) | E \text{ has good reduction mod v}\}$?**

**2) If not, are there some (nice) conditions one can ask on $E$ that make this result true? For instance, is $E$ isogenous to a curve for which 1) is true?** (see the answer by the user tracing)

Answer (score 2):

Well, in the meantime I found a counter-example to my question 1):

$E/\mathbb{Q}$ defined by $y^2=x^3+x$ with discriminant $\Delta=-2^5$. We have $E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}}=\{O,(0,0)\}$, but one can check that $4|\# E(\mathbb{F_p})$ for every $p \geq 3$ (this is Silverman AEC, exercise 5.12).

Answer (score 2):

One point to note is that $a_p,$ and hence #$E(\mathbb F_p)$, is an isogeny invariant, while #$E(\mathbb Q)_{\mathrm{torsion}}$ is not.

E.g. the curve $y^2 = x^3 + x$, which is curve 64.a4 on the [LMFBD tables](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/64/a/4), is isogenous to some other curves which *do* have 4 torsion points (see [the table](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/64/a/) for the isogeny class 64.a).

Comment: Thank you for your remark! But that raises the question: is it true that every $E$ is isogenous to an $E'$ for which my first question is true?

Comment: Yes, it does, but I avoided saying so, since I don't know the answer off the top of my head.  I see how to prove that if $\ell$ is a prime, and $\ell$ divides a.a. #$E(\mathbb F_p)$, then $E$ is isogenous to a curve with a rational point of order $\ell$.   (E.g. this would apply with $\ell = 5$ to the curve 11.a1 , which has trivial MW gp., but is isogenous to 11.a2 and 11.a3, which each have a $5$-torsion point.)  But the case of say $\ell^2$ isn't clear to me right now.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have pointed out, the answer to (1) is no.

The answer to (2) is *yes*. The relevant reference is [Katz, N.M. Galois properties of torsion points on abelian varieties. *Invent Math* **62**, 481–502 (1981)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01394256), in which Katz proves that, if $E/K$ is an elliptic curve over a number field, then the following are equivalent:

1. $N\mid \#E(\mathbb F_v)$ for all but finitely many places $v$ of $K$
2. There is an elliptic curve $E'$, isogenous to $E$ over $K$, such that $N\mid E'(K)_{\mathrm{tors}}$.

Katz's proof is entirely algebraic. It's quite easy to reduce to the case that $N = \ell^n$ is a prime power. Let $\rho_\ell=T_\ell(E)\otimes\mathbb Q_\ell\colon G_K\to \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Q_\ell)$ be the $\ell$-adic Galois representation associated to $E$. Then the first condition is equivalent to
$$\#E(\mathbb F_v) = N(v) + 1 - a_p = \det(1-\rho_\ell(\mathrm{Frob})_v)\equiv 0\pmod {\ell^n}$$
for all but finitely many places $v$ of $K$.

On the other hand, there is a dictionary between curves $E'$ that are $\ell$-power isogenous to $E$ and $G_K$-stable lattices inside $\rho_\ell$. Katz proves that, if $\det(1-\rho_\ell(\mathrm{Frob})_v)\equiv 0\pmod {\ell^n}$
for all but finitely many places $v$ of $K$, then there are  $G_K$-stable lattices $\mathcal L\supset \mathcal L'$ such that $\mathcal {L/L'}$ has order $\ell^n$ and $G_K$ acts trivially on $\mathcal {L/L'}$. The desired $E'$ is then the elliptic curve such that $\mathcal L' \cong T_\ell(E')$.